# Spring version of java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, spring, concurrency

I want to run some threads simultaneously which executes a given runnable task at regular intervals. Each thread will have its own instance of `Runnable` task.

I found out `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` which seems to fulfill my requirement.

Does there exist any Spring class which provides same functionality? and if yes, which one is better is to use.

Thanks

Jitendra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.html is what I wanted. It is a wrapper around `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to have a look at Spring's `org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`. The reference documentation has a [good example](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-executor).

Comment: ThreadPoolTaskExecutor seems to execute task only once. I want to schedule it to get executed at regular intervals. I just found out org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler
which seems to have these functionalities.

Could anyone please give me some comparison between both.

Comment: One way to do this would be to annotate a method with `@Scheduled` and programmatically invoke `execute` on your task executor. The `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` lets you define a cron expression for running a thread poll executor regularly. The `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` simply just executes a task using a thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch allows for invoking a method according to a cron string.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Quartz schedular provides the `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` functionality you are looking for. Refer to

> 22.2.2. Using the MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean and 
>   22.2.3. Wiring up jobs using triggers and the SchedulerFactoryBean for details @

[Chapter 22. Scheduling jobs using Quartz or Timer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/reference/scheduling.html).
We used in one of the project to schedule jobs at fixed intervals using cron expression. You can also restrict concurrent initiation of a Job if the previous job is still running.